# extracting text R between special characters

Tags: r, string, character, special-characters, extract

I have multiple strings as shown below:

```
filename="numbers [www.imagesplitter.net]-0-0.jpeg"
filename1="numbers [www.imagesplitter.net]-0-1.jpeg"
filename2="numbers [www.imagesplitter.net]-19-9.jpeg"
```

I want the text that appears between the second "-" and the last period.
I would like to get 0,1,9 respectively.

How do I do this? I am not sure how to detect the second "-" and the last period.

Comment: not fancy: `substr(x <- gsub('.jpeg', '', "numbers [www.imagesplitter.net]-19-9.jpeg"), nchar(x), nchar(x))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
sub('^[^-]*-[^-]*-(\\d+)\\..*$', '\\1', files)
#[1] "0" "1" "9"
```

or

```
 gsub('^[^-]*-[^-]*-|\\..*$', '', files)
 #[1] "0" "1" "9"
```

#### data

```
files <- c(filename, filename1, filename2)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would simply use `strsplit` to split the strings accordingly here:

```
sapply(strsplit(files, '[-.]'), '[', 5)
# [1] "0" "1" "9"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
files=c(filename, filename1, filename2)

sub(".*-(.+)\\.jpeg", "\\1", files)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `regmatches` function also.

```
> x <- c("numbers [www.imagesplitter.net]-0-0.jpeg","numbers [www.imagesplitter.net]-0-1.jpeg", "numbers [www.imagesplitter.net]-19-9.jpeg")
> unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr("^(?:[^-]*-){2}\\K.*(?=\\.)", x, perl=TRUE)))
[1] "0" "1" "9"
```

You could use the same regex in `stringr` , `str_extract_all` function also.

```
> library(stringr)
> unlist(str_extract_all(x, perl("^(?:[^-]*-){2}\\K.*(?=\\.)")))
[1] "0" "1" "9"
```

**OR**

```
> unlist(str_extract_all(x, perl("(?<=-)[^-.]*(?=\\.)")))
[1] "0" "1" "9"
```

OR

```
> unlist(str_extract_all(x, perl(".*-\\K\\d+")))
[1] "0" "1" "9"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
sub("^[^-]+-[^-]+-(.*)\\.[^\\.]*$", "\\1", c(filename, filename1, filename2))
[1] "0" "1" "9"
```